# Mono bug? CS0219 warning when variable is actually used

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

MonoDevelop (2.10.8) is reporting:

```
JPGCorruptForm.cs(20,20): Warning CS0219: The variable `myStream' is assigned but its value is never used (CS0219) (JPGCorrupt)
```

For this function:

```
    private void toolStripButtonChooseText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = ".";
        openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = false;

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Stop();

            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    _settings.TextFile = openFileDialog.FileName;
                    CurrentTextFile = _settings.TextFile;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my frist mono test project and I'm not sure if this kind of thing is normal. It certainly is not fatal, but could get annoying.

Comment: I think the warning message is clear enough to understand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you're *assigning* a value to the variable, but you're never actually *reading* from it. In other words, you could easily remove it, just changing the middle expression to:

```
if (openFileDialog.OpenFile() != null)
```

Note that your existing code doesn't actually *read* from the variable even though you might think it does in the comparison to null. It's more like this:

```
Stream tmp = openFileDialog.OpenFile();
myStream = tmp;
if (tmp != null)
```

It sounds like you probably *should* be using it, to close the stream if nothing else... although I'd then declare it as late as possible, like this:

```
using (Stream myStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile())
{
    if (myStream != null)
    {
        _settings.TextFile = openFileDialog.FileName;
        CurrentTextFile = _settings.TextFile;
    }
}
```

Here's a simpler example of the same problem, but the way:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string x;

        if ((x = "Hello") != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yes");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that with warning level 4 (and possibly lower ones), the Microsoft C# 4 compiler picks up on it too:

```
Test.cs(7,16): warning CS0219: The variable 'x' is assigned but its value is
        never used
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. The set() for CurrentTextFile opens the file and thus I really want it closed before that is called. Now that I understand my mistake I'm gonna rework this a bit.

Comment: Microsoft C# 4 compiler picks up on your example, but would't catch the original case, since it only raises CS0219 when the RHS of the assignment operation is a compile-time constant. (See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10629031/177018).